# 2-dimensional functions of random variables with piecewise densities

Tags: probability, density-function, piecewise-pdf

From Meyer's Introductory Probability and Statistical Applications, 2nd ed:

Suppose that the dimensions, $X$ and $Y$, of a rectangular metal plate may be considered to be independent continuous random variables with the following pdfs:

$$X: g(x) = \begin{cases}
x - 1, & 1 < x \leq 2 \\
-x + 3, & 2 < x < 3 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$$Y: h(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, & 2 < y < 4 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Find the pdf of the area of the plate, $A = XY$.

**My attempt**: for two independent continuous random variables $X, Y$ with pdfs $g(x)$ and $h(y)$, we know that if $W = XY$, then $p(w) = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} g(u) h \Big( \frac{a}{u} \Big) \Big| \frac{1}{u} \Big| \ dx$.  To find the integration bounds, I took the first interval $1 < x \leq 2$ and derived, using $a = xy$ and $2 < y < 4$:

\begin{align}
\implies 2 < &\frac{a}{x} < 4 \\
\implies 2x < &a < 4x \\
\end{align}

$$\implies 1 < x < \frac{a}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{a}{4} < x < 2$$

Similarly, I apply the same procedure to the $2 < x < 3$ portion of the pdf of $X$ and derive the following bounds:

$$2 < x < \frac{a}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{a}{4} < x < 3$$

Using the aforementioned result to derive each segment of the piecewise pdf of $A$, I get:

\begin{align}
\int^{a/2}_1 g(u) h \Big( \frac{a}{u} \Big) \frac{1}{u} \ du &= \int^{a/2}_1 (x-1)(1/2)(1/x) \ dx \\
&= \frac{a-2}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{a}{2}, \quad (2 < a < 4) \\
\int^{2}_{a/4} g(u) h \Big( \frac{a}{u} \Big) \frac{1}{u} \ du &= \int^{2}_{a/4} (x-1)(1/2)(1/x) \ dx \\
&= \frac{8-a}{8} + \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{a}{8}, \quad (4 < a < 8) \\
\int^{a/2}_{2} g(u) h \Big( \frac{a}{u} \Big) \frac{1}{u} \ du &= \int^{a/2}_2 (-x + 3)(1/2)(1/x) \ dx \\
&= \frac{4-a}{4} + \frac{3}{2} \ln \frac{a}{4}, \quad (4 < a < 6) \\
\int^{3}_{a/4} g(u) h \Big( \frac{a}{u} \Big) \frac{1}{u} \ du &= \int^{3}_{a/4} (-x + 3)(1/2)(1/x) \ dx \\
&= \frac{a-12}{8} + \frac{3}{2} \ln \frac{12}{a}, \quad (8 < a < 12)
\end{align}

Therefore, the pdf $p(a)$ may be defined as:

$$p(a) = \begin{cases}
\frac{a-2}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{a}{2}, &(2 < a < 4) \\
\frac{16-3a}{8} + \ln \frac{a^2}{16 \sqrt{2}}, &(4 < a < 6) \\
\frac{8-a}{8} + \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{a}{8}, &(6 < a < 8) \\
\frac{a-12}{8} + \frac{3}{2} \ln \frac{12}{a}, &(8 < a < 12)
\end{cases}$$

However, integrating each segment over their respective bounds fails to yield unity. Graphically, it appears that there is an issue with the segment on $6 < a < 8$. **My question**: what is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV!  One suggestion: Simplify.  Breaking $X$ at $2$ exhibits it as an equal mixture of two triangular distributions and in either case you don't have to grapple with the cumbersome piecewise notation.

Comment: [Also asked on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645493/15941).  Please don't post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: BTW, making a careful sketch of key contours of the product function $xy$ on the support $[1,3]\times [2,4]$ of this distribution gives a strong clue.  The contour values to plot are those passing through the vertices $(1,2),$ $(1,4),$ $(2,2),$ $(2,4),$ $(3,2),$ and $(3,4)$ and therefore are $2, 4, 6, 8,$ and $12.$  Look closely at the region between contours $6$ and $8.$